# Unable to find (and uninstall) installed version of CUDA

Tags: centos, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA version 10.0, but it is telling me a newer version is already installed. I am not able to find the newer version, so I can't run the uninstaller. I am on CentOS 7. Here's what I did:

I used wget to get the rpm and then tried to install it with
`sudo rpm -i cuda-repo-rhel7-10.0.130-1.x86_64.rpm` I get the following:

```
package cuda-repo-rhel7-10.1.105-1.x86_64 (which is newer than cuda-repo-rhel7-10.0.130-1.x86_64) is already installed
```

However, if I run `nvcc --version` I get: `-bash: nvcc: command not found`. `which nvcc` also doesn't show anything.

I checked in usr/local and I have directories for cuda-7.5, cuda-9.0, cuda, and cuda-8.0. The cuda folder contains 9.0 in it. How can I find the installed version of CUDA and uninstall it?

Based on a comment, I have added some outputs:
`yum list available | grep cuda` results in:

```
cuda.x86_64                              10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-10-0.x86_64                         10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-10-1.x86_64                         10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-7-0.x86_64                          7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-7-5.x86_64                          7.5-18                          cuda   
cuda-8-0.x86_64                          8.0.61-1                        cuda   
cuda-9-0.x86_64                          9.0.176-1                       cuda   
cuda-9-1.x86_64                          9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-9-2.x86_64                          9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-command-line-tools-10-0.x86_64      10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-command-line-tools-10-1.x86_64      10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-command-line-tools-7-0.x86_64       7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-command-line-tools-9-1.x86_64       9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-command-line-tools-9-2.x86_64       9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-compat-10-0.x86_64                  1:410.104-1.el7                 cuda   
cuda-compat-10-1.x86_64                  1:418.40.04-1                   cuda   
cuda-compiler-10-0.x86_64                10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-compiler-10-1.x86_64                10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-compiler-9-1.x86_64                 9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-compiler-9-2.x86_64                 9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-core-10-0.x86_64                    10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-core-10-1.x86_64                    10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-core-7-0.x86_64                     7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-core-9-1.x86_64                     9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-core-9-2.x86_64                     9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-cublas-10-0.x86_64                  10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cublas-7-0.x86_64                   7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-cublas-9-1.x86_64                   9.1.85.3-1                      cuda   
cuda-cublas-9-2.x86_64                   9.2.148.1-1                     cuda   
cuda-cublas-dev-10-0.x86_64              10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cublas-dev-7-0.x86_64               7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-cublas-dev-9-1.x86_64               9.1.85.3-1                      cuda   
cuda-cublas-dev-9-2.x86_64               9.2.148.1-1                     cuda   
cuda-cudart-10-0.x86_64                  10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cudart-10-1.x86_64                  10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-cudart-7-0.x86_64                   7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-cudart-9-1.x86_64                   9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-cudart-9-2.x86_64                   9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-cudart-dev-10-0.x86_64              10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cudart-dev-10-1.x86_64              10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-cudart-dev-7-0.x86_64               7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-cudart-dev-9-1.x86_64               9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-cudart-dev-9-2.x86_64               9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-cufft-10-0.x86_64                   10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cufft-10-1.x86_64                   10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-cufft-7-0.x86_64                    7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-cufft-9-1.x86_64                    9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-cufft-9-2.x86_64                    9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-cufft-dev-10-0.x86_64               10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cufft-dev-10-1.x86_64               10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-cufft-dev-7-0.x86_64                7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-cufft-dev-9-1.x86_64                9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-cufft-dev-9-2.x86_64                9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-cuobjdump-10-0.x86_64               10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cuobjdump-10-1.x86_64               10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-cuobjdump-9-1.x86_64                9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-cuobjdump-9-2.x86_64                9.2.148.1-1                     cuda   
cuda-cupti-10-0.x86_64                   10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cupti-10-1.x86_64                   10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-cupti-9-1.x86_64                    9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-cupti-9-2.x86_64                    9.2.148.1-1                     cuda   
cuda-curand-10-0.x86_64                  10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-curand-10-1.x86_64                  10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-curand-7-0.x86_64                   7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-curand-9-1.x86_64                   9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-curand-9-2.x86_64                   9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-curand-dev-10-0.x86_64              10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-curand-dev-10-1.x86_64              10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-curand-dev-7-0.x86_64               7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-curand-dev-9-1.x86_64               9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-curand-dev-9-2.x86_64               9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-cusolver-10-0.x86_64                10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cusolver-10-1.x86_64                10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-cusolver-7-0.x86_64                 7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-cusolver-9-1.x86_64                 9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-cusolver-9-2.x86_64                 9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-cusolver-dev-10-0.x86_64            10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cusolver-dev-10-1.x86_64            10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-cusolver-dev-7-0.x86_64             7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-cusolver-dev-9-1.x86_64             9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-cusolver-dev-9-2.x86_64             9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-cusparse-10-0.x86_64                10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cusparse-10-1.x86_64                10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-cusparse-7-0.x86_64                 7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-cusparse-9-1.x86_64                 9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-cusparse-9-2.x86_64                 9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-cusparse-dev-10-0.x86_64            10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-cusparse-dev-10-1.x86_64            10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-cusparse-dev-7-0.x86_64             7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-cusparse-dev-9-1.x86_64             9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-cusparse-dev-9-2.x86_64             9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-demo-suite-10-0.x86_64              10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-demo-suite-10-1.x86_64              10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-demo-suite-8-0.x86_64               8.0.61-1                        cuda   
cuda-demo-suite-9-0.x86_64               9.0.176-1                       cuda   
cuda-demo-suite-9-1.x86_64               9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-demo-suite-9-2.x86_64               9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-documentation-10-0.x86_64           10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-documentation-10-1.x86_64           10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-documentation-7-0.x86_64            7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-documentation-9-1.x86_64            9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-documentation-9-2.x86_64            9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-driver-dev-10-0.x86_64              10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-driver-dev-10-1.x86_64              10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-driver-dev-7-0.x86_64               7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-driver-dev-9-1.x86_64               9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-driver-dev-9-2.x86_64               9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-drivers.x86_64                      418.40.04-1                     cuda   
cuda-drivers-diagnostic.x86_64           418.40.04-1                     cuda   
cuda-gdb-10-0.x86_64                     10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-gdb-10-1.x86_64                     10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-gdb-9-1.x86_64                      9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-gdb-9-2.x86_64                      9.2.148.1-1                     cuda   
cuda-gdb-src-10-0.x86_64                 10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-gdb-src-10-1.x86_64                 10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-gdb-src-7-0.x86_64                  7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-gdb-src-7-5.x86_64                  7.5-18                          cuda   
cuda-gdb-src-8-0.x86_64                  8.0.61-1                        cuda   
cuda-gdb-src-9-0.x86_64                  9.0.176-1                       cuda   
cuda-gdb-src-9-1.x86_64                  9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-gdb-src-9-2.x86_64                  9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-0.x86_64     10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-1.x86_64     10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-gpu-library-advisor-9-1.x86_64      9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-gpu-library-advisor-9-2.x86_64      9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-libraries-10-0.x86_64               10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-libraries-10-1.x86_64               10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-libraries-9-1.x86_64                9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-libraries-9-2.x86_64                9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-libraries-dev-10-0.x86_64           10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-libraries-dev-10-1.x86_64           10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-libraries-dev-9-1.x86_64            9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-libraries-dev-9-2.x86_64            9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-license-10-0.x86_64                 10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-license-10-1.x86_64                 10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-license-7-0.x86_64                  7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-license-9-1.x86_64                  9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-license-9-2.x86_64                  9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-memcheck-10-0.x86_64                10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-memcheck-10-1.x86_64                10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-memcheck-9-1.x86_64                 9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-memcheck-9-2.x86_64                 9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-minimal-build-10-0.x86_64           10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-minimal-build-10-1.x86_64           10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-minimal-build-7-0.x86_64            7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-minimal-build-7-5.x86_64            7.5-18                          cuda   
cuda-minimal-build-8-0.x86_64            8.0.61-1                        cuda   
cuda-minimal-build-9-0.x86_64            9.0.176-1                       cuda   
cuda-minimal-build-9-1.x86_64            9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-minimal-build-9-2.x86_64            9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-misc-headers-10-0.x86_64            10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-misc-headers-10-1.x86_64            10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-misc-headers-7-0.x86_64             7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-misc-headers-9-1.x86_64             9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-misc-headers-9-2.x86_64             9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-npp-10-0.x86_64                     10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-npp-10-1.x86_64                     10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-npp-7-0.x86_64                      7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-npp-9-1.x86_64                      9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-npp-9-2.x86_64                      9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-npp-dev-10-0.x86_64                 10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-npp-dev-10-1.x86_64                 10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-npp-dev-7-0.x86_64                  7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-npp-dev-9-1.x86_64                  9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-npp-dev-9-2.x86_64                  9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-nsight-10-0.x86_64                  10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nsight-10-1.x86_64                  10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nsight-9-1.x86_64                   9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nsight-9-2.x86_64                   9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-nsight-compute-10-0.x86_64          10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nsight-compute-10-1.x86_64          10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nsight-systems-10-1.x86_64          10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvcc-10-0.x86_64                    10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvcc-10-1.x86_64                    10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvcc-9-1.x86_64                     9.1.85.2-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvcc-9-2.x86_64                     9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-nvdisasm-10-0.x86_64                10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvdisasm-10-1.x86_64                10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvdisasm-9-1.x86_64                 9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nvdisasm-9-2.x86_64                 9.2.148.1-1                     cuda   
cuda-nvgraph-10-0.x86_64                 10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvgraph-10-1.x86_64                 10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvgraph-9-1.x86_64                  9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nvgraph-9-2.x86_64                  9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-0.x86_64             10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-1.x86_64             10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-1.x86_64              9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-2.x86_64              9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-nvidia-kmod-common.x86_64           352.99-0                        cuda   
cuda-nvjpeg-10-0.x86_64                  10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvjpeg-10-1.x86_64                  10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-0.x86_64              10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-1.x86_64              10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvml-dev-10-0.x86_64                10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvml-dev-10-1.x86_64                10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvml-dev-9-1.x86_64                 9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nvml-dev-9-2.x86_64                 9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-nvprof-10-0.x86_64                  10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvprof-10-1.x86_64                  10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvprof-9-1.x86_64                   9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nvprof-9-2.x86_64                   9.2.148.1-1                     cuda   
cuda-nvprune-10-0.x86_64                 10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvprune-10-1.x86_64                 10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvprune-9-1.x86_64                  9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nvprune-9-2.x86_64                  9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-nvrtc-10-0.x86_64                   10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvrtc-10-1.x86_64                   10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvrtc-7-0.x86_64                    7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-nvrtc-9-1.x86_64                    9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nvrtc-9-2.x86_64                    9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-0.x86_64               10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-1.x86_64               10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvrtc-dev-7-0.x86_64                7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-1.x86_64                9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-2.x86_64                9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-nvtx-10-0.x86_64                    10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvtx-10-1.x86_64                    10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvtx-9-1.x86_64                     9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nvtx-9-2.x86_64                     9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-nvvp-10-0.x86_64                    10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvvp-10-1.x86_64                    10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-nvvp-9-1.x86_64                     9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-nvvp-9-2.x86_64                     9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-runtime-10-0.x86_64                 10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-runtime-10-1.x86_64                 10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-runtime-7-0.x86_64                  7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-runtime-7-5.x86_64                  7.5-18                          cuda   
cuda-runtime-8-0.x86_64                  8.0.61-1                        cuda   
cuda-runtime-9-0.x86_64                  9.0.176-1                       cuda   
cuda-runtime-9-1.x86_64                  9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-runtime-9-2.x86_64                  9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-samples-10-0.x86_64                 10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-samples-10-1.x86_64                 10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-samples-7-0.x86_64                  7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-samples-9-1.x86_64                  9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-samples-9-2.x86_64                  9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-sanitizer-api-10-1.x86_64           10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-toolkit-10-0.x86_64                 10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-toolkit-10-1.x86_64                 10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-toolkit-7-0.x86_64                  7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-toolkit-9-1.x86_64                  9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-toolkit-9-2.x86_64                  9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-tools-10-0.x86_64                   10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-tools-10-1.x86_64                   10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-tools-9-1.x86_64                    9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-tools-9-2.x86_64                    9.2.148-1                       cuda   
cuda-visual-tools-10-0.x86_64            10.0.130-1                      cuda   
cuda-visual-tools-10-1.x86_64            10.1.105-1                      cuda   
cuda-visual-tools-7-0.x86_64             7.0-28                          cuda   
cuda-visual-tools-9-1.x86_64             9.1.85-1                        cuda   
cuda-visual-tools-9-2.x86_64             9.2.148-1                       cuda   
dkms-nvidia.x86_64                       3:418.40.04-1.el7               cuda   
gpu-deployment-kit.x86_64                352.93-0                        cuda   
libcublas-devel.x86_64                   10.1.0.105-1                    cuda   
libcublas10.x86_64                       10.1.0.105-1                    cuda   
libglvnd-debuginfo.x86_64                1:1.0.1-0.6.git5baa1e5.el7      cuda   
nvidia-driver.x86_64                     3:418.40.04-4.el7               cuda   
nvidia-driver-NVML.x86_64                3:418.40.04-4.el7               cuda   
nvidia-driver-NvFBCOpenGL.x86_64         3:418.40.04-4.el7               cuda   
nvidia-driver-cuda.x86_64                3:418.40.04-4.el7               cuda   
nvidia-driver-cuda-libs.x86_64           3:418.40.04-4.el7               cuda   
nvidia-driver-devel.x86_64               3:418.40.04-4.el7               cuda   
nvidia-driver-diagnostic.x86_64          3:418.40.04-4.el7               cuda   
nvidia-driver-libs.x86_64                3:418.40.04-4.el7               cuda   
nvidia-kmod.x86_64                       1:396.82-2.el7                  cuda   
nvidia-libXNVCtrl.x86_64                 3:418.40.04-1.el7               cuda   
nvidia-libXNVCtrl-devel.x86_64           3:418.40.04-1.el7               cuda   
nvidia-modprobe.x86_64                   3:418.40.04-1.el7               cuda   
nvidia-persistenced.x86_64               3:418.40.04-1.el7               cuda   
nvidia-settings.x86_64                   3:418.40.04-1.el7               cuda   
nvidia-uvm-kmod.x86_64                   1:352.99-3.el7                  cuda   
nvidia-xconfig.x86_64                    3:418.40.04-1.el7               cuda   
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia.x86_64               1:396.82-1.el7                  cuda   
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-devel.x86_64         1:396.82-1.el7                  cuda   
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-diagnostic.x86_64    1:396.82-1.el7                  cuda   
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-gl.x86_64            1:396.82-1.el7                  cuda   
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs.x86_64          1:396.82-1.el7                  cuda
```

`rpm -qa | grep cuda` results in:

```
cuda-toolkit-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cublas-dev-8-0-8.0.61.2-1.x86_64
cuda-toolkit-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-license-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cusparse-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-curand-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-license-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cusolver-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cusparse-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cufft-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cufft-dev-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-samples-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cufft-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-cudart-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-npp-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-documentation-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-nvrtc-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-nvgraph-dev-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-npp-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-npp-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-nvgraph-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-command-line-tools-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cublas-8-0-8.0.61.2-1.x86_64
cuda-libraries-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-samples-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cufft-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-cusolver-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-cudart-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-cublas-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cusparse-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cudart-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-curand-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-documentation-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-repo-rhel7-10.1.105-1.x86_64
cuda-toolkit-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-nvrtc-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-curand-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-npp-dev-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-core-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cusolver-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-command-line-tools-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-license-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-nvrtc-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-cusparse-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-misc-headers-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-command-line-tools-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-cublas-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-visual-tools-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-driver-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-nvml-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cudart-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-curand-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-visual-tools-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cublas-dev-9-0-9.0.176.4-1.x86_64
cuda-core-9-0-9.0.176.3-1.x86_64
cuda-nvrtc-dev-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-curand-dev-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cufft-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cudart-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cusolver-dev-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cublas-9-0-9.0.176.4-1.x86_64
cuda-nvrtc-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-core-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-npp-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-samples-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-nvgraph-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-npp-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-nvml-dev-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-misc-headers-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cudart-dev-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-visual-tools-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-libraries-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-documentation-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-driver-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-cusolver-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-curand-dev-7-5-7.5-18.x86_64
cuda-driver-dev-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-cusparse-dev-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
cuda-cufft-dev-9-0-9.0.176-1.x86_64
cuda-misc-headers-8-0-8.0.61-1.x86_64
```

EDIT 2:
It looks like cuda isn't actually installed, because running this command
`sudo yum install cuda` downloads and installs it.

Comment: Add the output of `yum list available | grep cuda` and `rpm -qa | grep cuda` to your question.

Comment: @NasirRiley I updated the post

Comment: The `cuda-repo-rhel7-10.1.105-1.x86_64` looks like it only sets up the repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d` and catches packages and updates from Nvidia servers and you already got an upgrade of that package. Just install cuda with `yum install cuda` which should pull in version 10.1.105.

Comment: @Thomas so how do I install an older version?

Comment: To install a specific version `yum install cuda-9-2.x86_64` should install the 9.2 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the repo for `cuda 10.1.105-1` available. That is why it installed with `yum install cuda`

You also already have `cuda 8-0-8.0.61-1` and `cuda 9-0-9.0.176-1` installed.

If you want a different older version installed such as `10.0.130-1` then use this command:

```
yum install cuda-10-0
```

That will install it and all of its dependencies.

You will then need to prepend it to your `PATH` and `LD_LIBARRY_PATH`.

Add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then log out and back in.

That is assuming that you want `cuda-10.0`. If you don't then replace 10.0 with the version that you want with `yum install cuda-` and in prepending it to your `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.bashrc`.